# Ionic image selector and picker is not working in IOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to select image from image gallery and upload into server but unfortunately its not working in some case.

I have tried **cordova-plugin-camera** to select picture from device I tried with below method.

```
  navigator.camera.getPicture
```

But when I select this some time its working fine and some time its throw error:

```
Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined
```

So now I tried it with different plugin which in **cordova-imagePicker**

```
  $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
.then(function (results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
  }
}, function(error) {
  // error getting photos
});
```

Its also doing the same thing sometime working fine in device and sometime throwing error:

```
Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'n.imagePicker.getPicture')
```

I tried with same solution some time its fine but some time its throwing error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look answer, it might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337017/open-the-image-gallery-with-ionic-angularjs/31337272#31337272

Comment: what is the difference between `org.apache.cordova.camera` and simple `cordova-plugin-camera`

Comment: org.apache.cordova.camera is old deprecated id for this plugin and cordova-plugin-camera is new id for plugin for camera, but depercated still work

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/), it's not the same as Cordova and then you put it in the module inside the brackets as ['ngCordova'], finally you install the [imagePicker](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/) and you inject the $cordovaImagePicker inside the parameters of your controller. Then you can use the function you are using